# Android: Odd display behaviour

Tags: android, layout, background, android-edittext

Hopefully someone could help me with identifying why the odd display issues.

I am loading an xml with a couple buttons and Edit Texts, though it changed the appearance on me from what I was designing it as in Eclipse and what the emulator runs and what the tablet runs. The edit text is the big issue for me because it is essentially hidden into the background.

I cannot adjust the android:background="@android:color/white" because that changes the entire look. I just wanted what was displayed in Eclipse as I was designing it.

[image: Odd Edit text and button display]

My xml file as I have it right now,

-- EDIT full XML -- Note: this is brought into a sliding drawer with the 'include' methodology. Let me know if that one would be required as well.

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Active Sync" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@android:color/white" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Account" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Sync Settings" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText1"
                            android:layout_width="0dip"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:text="Edit" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="100" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:text="Load CSV"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:text="Load Excel"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="35"
                            android:text="Add Manual"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <HorizontalScrollView
                            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/editText2"
                                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:hint="#" >
                                    </EditText>

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/editText3"
                                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:hint="Manufacturer" >
                                    </EditText>


                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/editText4"
                                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:hint="Model" >
                                    </EditText>
...
```

Is there a 'default' or 'strict' appearance that I can select to keep the default as it is displayed in Eclipse?

Comment: The XML you have given here is stripped. Please correct that.

Comment: What do you mean by stripped? you want all of it?

Comment: Yes, so that we could simply test it. And as Sam_D's answer you can try putting a background, but not a white one, Android uses 9-patch for such purposes. But yes it is cumbersome! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping each EditText in a ViewGroup such as LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, and give the ViewGroup a white background.

Comment: I gave that a try and it ends up putting a white behind it. Though it starts to look archaic and loses the aesthetic appeal from the start. You cannot even tell that it might be an editable field.

http://s13.postimage.org/qegqq4is7/test2.png